# jQuery: Show div depending on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select[name=payment]').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value == "debit") {
      $(".box").not(".debit").hide();
      $(".debit").show();
    } else if (value == "transfer") {
      $(".box").not(".transfer").hide();
      $(".transfer").show();
    }
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select name="payment">
    <option data-calc="0" value="" disabled selected>Chose payment ↓</option>
    <option value="transfer">transfer</option>
    <option value="debit">debit</option>
</select>

<div class="debit box">debit</div>
<div class="transfer box">transfer</div>

</body>
</html>
```

That works very good. But I don't want to call my class `debit box`. I want to call it `debit` instead.

That means `<div class="debit">debit</div>` instead of `<div class="debit box">debit</div>`.

How can I get rid of this `box` thing?

Comment: Do you mean: change `$(".box").not(".debit").hide();` to `$(".transfer").hide()` and `$(".box").not(".transfer").hide();` to `$(".debit").hide();`  the current code is much more robust.

Comment: *"I want to call it debit"* - it's already "called" `debit`.   What are you *actually* trying to do that this does not let you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all the boxes inside another DIV.

```
<div id="boxes">
    <div class="debit box">debit</div>
    <div class="transfer box">transfer</div>
</div>
```

Then you can do:

```
$("#boxes > div").hide();
$(".debit").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the className to be debit, and identify it with this classname in the jquery hide method, then the method should look like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select[name=payment]').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value == "debit") {
      $(".transfer").hide();
      $(".debit").show();
    } else if (value == "transfer") {
      $(".debit").hide();
      $(".transfer").show();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

But I think it highlights that you want what Barmar suggests because you'll need to update hiding and showing manually for any choice element you'll add. But for two elements this might be ok.

Answer (score 0):

This might be works for you:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select[name=payment]').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(".boxes div").hide();
    $("." + $value).show();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select name="payment">
    <option data-calc="0" value="" disabled selected>Chose payment ↓</option>
    <option value="transfer">transfer</option>
    <option value="debit">debit</option>
</select>
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="debit">debit</div>
    <div class="transfer">transfer</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```